# Memory safety in swift (inout param/long term access)

Tags: swift, memory-safety

I was reading the memory safety chapter in swift, and wanted to try this exemple :

```
var stepSize = 1

func increment(_ number: inout Int) {
    number += stepSize
}

increment(&stepSize)
```

Event if it says that there is an error because of the conflicting access to the `stepsize` variable (long term access in writing), it actually compiles and give me the right answer (ie 2).

Can anyone give an exemple of when long term access to a variable will result in an error ? I can't come with one.

edit:

I tested with a playground on Xcode 9.2

Comment: It crashes with "Simultaneous accesses to 0x1003b8260" in my Xcode 9.2 and 9.3beta. – Btw, "undefined/unsafe behavior" does not mean that the result *has* to be wrong.

Comment: The behavior depends upon your project's "Exclusive access to memory" setting in the target's build settings, as well as potentially whether you do debug or release build.

Comment: See "Exclusive Access to Memory" in latter part of WWDC 2017 [What's New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/) video for examples where problems can arise.

Comment: Looks like playgrounds have dynamic exclusivity checks disabled by default. If you try it in an actual project (w/ default build settings), dynamic enforcement will catch the exclusive access violation, as Martin says.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in playground - the playground is not a perfect simulator.

Try "New -> Project -> Single View App"
This piece of code will crash (even on simulator) in runtime with something like:

```
Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x6000022b4310, but modification requires exclusive access
```